# How to create a loop that will output percentage in a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, group-by, percentage

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | A | Apples | Aisle 1 | N | Section 2 |
| S1 | A | Apples | Aisle 2 | Y | Section 2 |
| S1 | A | Apples | Aisle 1 | Y | Section 2 |
| S2 | A | Apples | Aisle 1 | N | Section 2 |
| S1 | B | Bananas | Aisle 2 | N | Section 2 |
| S1 | B | Bananas | Aisle 1 | N | Section 2 |

I need help writing a loop to calculate the percentage of appearance for each combination of records. I want COL1 to be ignored in this calculation. The Key identifiers are COL2 and COL3 so I am thinking that I need to use a groupby on COL2 and COL3 then calculate the percentage of appearance for COL4-COL6 to get the result below. How can I achieve this?

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL4_PCT | COL5_PCT | COL6_PCT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | A | Apples | Aisle 1 | N | Section 2 | .75 | .50 | 1 |
| S1 | A | Apples | Aisle 2 | Y | Section 2 | .25 | .50 | 1 |
| S1 | A | Apples | Aisle 1 | Y | Section 2 | .75 | .50 | 1 |
| S2 | A | Apples | Aisle 1 | N | Section 2 | .75 | .50 | 1 |
| S1 | B | Bananas | Aisle 2 | N | Section 2 | .50 | 1 | 1 |
| S1 | B | Bananas | Aisle 1 | N | Section 2 | .50 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Do you actually need to write a loop, like if it's a requirement for homework, or do you just *think* you do? See [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](/q/16476924/4518341), TLDR: don't, if at all possible.

Comment: The `COL5` value in row 2 in the top table should be "Y" instead of "N" to match the bottom table.

Comment: @wjandrea, I am just trying to understand loop and how it would work in this instance. Plus, I thought a loop would be easier and faster to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can include each column individually in a `groupby` and `count`:

```
counter = df.groupby(["COL2","COL3"])["COL2"].transform("count")
for column in ["COL4", "COL5", "COL6"]:
    df[f"{column}_PCT"] = df.groupby(["COL2", "COL3", column])["COL2"].transform("count").div(counter)

>>> df
  COL1 COL2     COL3     COL4 COL5       COL6  COL4_PCT  COL5_PCT  COL6_PCT
0   S1    A   Apples  Aisle 1    N  Section 2      0.75       0.5       1.0
1   S1    A   Apples  Aisle 2    Y  Section 2      0.25       0.5       1.0
2   S1    A   Apples  Aisle 1    Y  Section 2      0.75       0.5       1.0
3   S2    A   Apples  Aisle 1    N  Section 2      0.75       0.5       1.0
4   S1    B  Bananas  Aisle 2    N  Section 2      0.50       1.0       1.0
5   S1    B  Bananas  Aisle 1    N  Section 2      0.50       1.0       1.0
```

Comment: `counter` is wrong if `COL1` is missing any values. OP said to ignore it anyway. Use the count of the column instead.

Comment: Yeah, what column is counted doesn't make a difference (I changed it anyway), and the example provided didn't have missing values.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice you're using `COL1` in the loop too. The same thing applies there. The problem is that `count` is for **non-missing** values, so also if any of COL4-COL6 are missing values, you'll get the wrong result.